# Get bias field using sitk

Tags: python, simpleitk, mri

I'm trying to use sitk library to clear biased Mr image (MRI).

I'm able to get the corrected image but can't get the bias image.

Set the following parameters:

```
shrink_factor=1,
mask_image=mask, 
number_of_iterations=100, 
number_of_fitting_levels=4
```

This is the code I tried

```
corrected_image = corrector.Execute(image, maskImage)

log_bias_field = corrector.GetLogBiasFieldAsImage(inputImage)
bias_exp = sitk.Cast(sitk.Exp(log_bias_field), sitk.sitkFloat64)
bias = inputImage / bias_exp
bias = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(bias)
bias = bias / bias.max()
```

But I get this image:

[image: bias^^]

Do you know how to get the bias only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the bias field function you need to decide on what resolution, for the full resolution image:

```
bias_field_full_resolution = sitk.Exp(corrector.GetLogBiasFieldAsImage(biased_image_full_resolution))
```

When calling the `Execute` method the bias field is estimated and the corrected image has the same resolution as the input, which is often a resampled version of the original biased image.

If we actually want to correct the image at the original resolution:

```
bias_field_full_resolution = sitk.Exp(corrector.GetLogBiasFieldAsImage(biased_image_full_resolution))
corrected_image_full_resolution = biased_image_full_resolution / bias_field_full_resolution
```